# How does Voxel Cone Tracing solve the rendering equation?

Tags: global-illumination, voxelization, raymarching

so I am not new to interactive graphics programming, but I wanted to try out advanced techniques. Currently I am struggling to understand how the author of the 2011 paper "Interactive Indirect Illumination Using Voxel Cone Tracing" (Crassin et al) manages to solve the rendering equation. Specifically in section 6 he claims that the hemisphere can be partitioned into a sum of integrals. I know about the Riemann sum, but this doesn't look like it.
So my question:
How does cone tracing as explained in the paper solve the rendering equation?

Comment: I just read your answer there

Comment: Indeed it's a duplicate, but I have another question which directly relates to your answer given in the other post. Should I ask there?

Comment: I cannot comment there sadly.

Comment: Since both my blogs and StackOverflow support Markdown and MathJax, see https://matt77hias.github.io/blog/2018/08/19/voxel-cone-tracing.html for Q&A as well ;-)

Comment: @DaOnlyOwner Then [edit](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/posts/8299/edit) this question to focus on the actual question you have and link to the other question for context.